# How do I perform spatial data analysis to kinesis streams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, iot

I'm quite new to AWS products and have been learning from their tutorials a lot. Recently I'm building an end-to-end IoT application to do near real time spatial analytics. So the scenario is that we will deploy several sensors in each room/space and examine the spatial correlation across all the sensor measurements every once a while (maybe every 10s). The iot sensor data payload would look like this:

{"roomid": 1,"sensorid":"s001", "value": 0.012}

Kinesis seems powerful for real time analytics, so Im sending data from IoT to kinesis stream, and then using kinesis analytics to perform data aggregation using tumbling window and enrich measurements with sensor locations. The processed data to be sent out would look like this now[pic]:

[kinesis analytics data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nl2g.png)

My plan was to send data from kinesis analytics to kinesis stream and then invoke lambda function to do spatial analysis. It seems that the records with same rowtime(process time) will be sent within a single event in kinesis stream. But I want to apply lambda function to each room separately, how can I separate these records from kinesis stream? (Am I using the wrong strategy?)

I'm also looking for a data storage solution for the sensor data. Any advice? There are many mature time-series DB but I want to find the best suitable DB for spatial analysis. Shall I look into graph DB, like Neo4j?

Thanks, 
Sasa

Comment: How much data is there?

Comment: For now, we are only testing with 1 group of 5 sensors, and each sensor is sending out json record with 1 sec interval. Each record size is about 50B. I hope using kinesis stream we can easily scale up to hundreds of sensor groups. @Grzesiek

Comment: @Sasa: if I understand right the first question, you want to use Kinesis Analytics to aggregate records by time and room, then you want to do spatial analysis on these records. I represent http://streamx.co, where we develop Drools Kinesis Analytics. At the moment we work on adding ability to invoke external services from the rules. Using this you will be able to invoke Lambda to perform spatial analysis and then continue processing your data. Let me know if you are interested in additional details.